# No me esta funcionando la función

Tags: javascript, funciones

Un gran saludo.

La dificultad que tengo es que estoy haciendo una especie de simulador de crédito, primero cuando le doy click en enviar no me arroja el resultado de las operaciones que coloque en el javascript, y necesito que me haga esa operación 12 veces, me explico, son doce resultados que varían, por eso los almacene en un arreglo pero al parecer algo esta mal.

Gracias.

```js
function prestamo()
{
var i,n,monto,k,cuotaf;

var abonoc =[n], interes =[n], saldocapital [n];
    
//Cuota Fija    

n=parseFloat(pla.value);
i=parseFloat(int.value);
monto=parseFloat(mon.value);


cuotaf=monto/((1-Math.pow(1+i,-n))/i);
document.write(cuotaf);


for(k=0; k<=n; k++)
{

//Abono capital
    
abonoc=cuotaf-interes;



// Intereses

interes=monto*i;


// Saldo Capital 

saldocapital=abonoc-monto; 


document.write (k,"   ",cuotaf,"   ",abonoc [n],"   ",interes[n], "  ",saldocapital[n],"  ");
document.write("<br>");
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simulador de credito</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
</head>
    
<body>
<h1><center>Simulador de crédito</center></h1>

<label>Tipo de credito</label>
<select name="tipo de credito">
<option value="opc1">Libre inversión</option>
<option value="opc2">Unificación de deudas</option>
<option value="opc3">Garantia de ahorro </option>
<option value="opc4">Remodelación</option>
</select>

<label>Plazo</label>
<input name="plazo" type="text" id="pla" style="text-align:right" value="12" size="10">
 
<br>
  
<label>Valor prestamo</label>
<input name="valor" type="text" id="mon" style="text-align:right" value="1200000" size="10"> 

<label>Interes</label>
<input name="int" type="text" id="int" value="0.023">

<br>
  
<input type="submit" name="bot" id="bot" value="Enviar" onClick="prestamo();">
    
    

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes inicializar las variables de los input y ademas los array puedes declararlos y después asignarlos por niveles.

```js
function prestamo() {
  var pla = document.getElementById("pla");
  var int = document.getElementById("int");
  var mon = document.getElementById("mon");
  
  var i, n, monto, k, cuotaf;
  
  n = parseFloat(pla.value);
  i = parseFloat(int.value);
  monto = parseFloat(mon.value);

  var abonoc,interes,saldocapital;

  //Cuota Fija
  cuotaf = monto / ((1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n)) / i);
  document.write(cuotaf);


  for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {

    //Abono capital

    abonoc[n] = cuotaf - interes;



    // Intereses

    interes[n] = monto * i;


    // Saldo Capital 

    saldocapital[n] = abonoc - monto;


    document.write(k, "   ", cuotaf, "   ", abonoc[n], "   ", interes[n], "  ", saldocapital[n], "  ");
    document.write("<br>");
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simulador de credito</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <center>Simulador de crédito</center>
  </h1>

  <label>Tipo de credito</label>
  <select name="tipo de credito">
<option value="opc1">Libre inversión</option>
<option value="opc2">Unificación de deudas</option>
<option value="opc3">Garantia de ahorro </option>
<option value="opc4">Remodelación</option>
</select>

  <label>Plazo</label>
  <input name="plazo" type="text" id="pla" style="text-align:right" value="12" size="10">

  <br>

  <label>Valor prestamo</label>
  <input name="valor" type="text" id="mon" style="text-align:right" value="1200000" size="10">

  <label>Interes</label>
  <input name="int" type="text" id="int" value="0.023">

  <br>

  <input type="submit" name="bot" id="bot" value="Enviar" onClick="prestamo();">


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que tienes una concepción completamente equivocada sobre Javascript

para empezar tienes una línea de código que al parecer estas inicializando un arreglo con un tamaño definido pero de forma errónea, por ejemplo la linea siguiente:

```
var abonoc = [n];
```

en este caso estas ingresando el valor `n` (que por cierto es `undefined` porque no le has asignado valor alguno) dentro del arreglo, si quieres hacer un arreglo de un tamaño definido (que no veo motivo para eso ya que un arreglo vacío de tamaño n no tiene mucho sentido) lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
var abonoc = new Array(4); // por ejemplo
```

otro problema que tienes es que estas utilizando los elementos html como si javascript los leyera magicamente, pero lo que debes hacer es instanciarlos, ejemplo:

```
var pla = document.getElementById('pla');
n = parseFloat(pla.value);
```

ese es el alcance que te puedo dar, tu código corregido sería el siguiente:

```js
function prestamo()
{
var i,n,monto,k,cuotaf;

var abonoc =[], interes =[], saldocapital = [];
    
//Cuota Fija    
var pla = document.getElementById('pla');
var int = document.getElementById('int');
var mon = document.getElementById('mon');
n=parseFloat(pla.value);
i=parseFloat(int.value);
monto=parseFloat(mon.value);


cuotaf=monto/((1-Math.pow(1+i,-n))/i);
document.write(cuotaf);


for(k=0; k<=n; k++)
{

//Abono capital
    
abonoc[k]=cuotaf-i;

// Intereses

interes[k]=monto*i;


// Saldo Capital 

saldocapital[k]=abonoc[k]-monto; 


document.write (k,"   ",cuotaf,"   ",abonoc[k],"   ",interes[k], "  ",saldocapital[k],"  ");
document.write("<br>");
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simulador de credito</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
</head>
    
<body>
<h1><center>Simulador de crédito</center></h1>

<label>Tipo de credito</label>
<select name="tipo de credito">
<option value="opc1">Libre inversión</option>
<option value="opc2">Unificación de deudas</option>
<option value="opc3">Garantia de ahorro </option>
<option value="opc4">Remodelación</option>
</select>

<label>Plazo</label>
<input name="plazo" type="text" id="pla" style="text-align:right" value="12" size="10">
 
<br>
  
<label>Valor prestamo</label>
<input name="valor" type="text" id="mon" style="text-align:right" value="1200000" size="10"> 

<label>Interes</label>
<input name="int" type="text" id="int" value="0.023">

<br>
  
<input type="submit" name="bot" id="bot" value="Enviar" onClick="prestamo();">
    
    

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Supongo es la manera en que estas intentando asignar el valor de n a otras variables. `var abonoc =[n], interes =[n], saldocapital [n];` quitale '[]' y si intentas acceder a cada valor del array seria n[0], n[1], etc